# undefined method `class_detail' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two tables `class_details` and `user_classes`. `user_classes` table is dependent of `user table` and `class_details`  and `class_details` is independent of user table. Now my requirement is that when i click a button few details must be saved to the database which belong to different tables. User dependent table are only getting saved to database and not the user independent tables and i am getting error `undefined method class_detail for nil:NilClass`

Controller code

```
def update_profile
    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to profile_index_path, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :index
    end
  end
end

private

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @user.fee || @user.build_fee
    @user.user_class || @user.build_user_class
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, fee_attributes: %i[id fee_hour fee_month], user_class_attributes: %i[id class_detail [id class_name class_category]])
  end
```

class_detail.rb

```
class ClassDetail < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user_class, dependent: :destroy
end
```

user_class.rb

```
class UserClass < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :class_details 

  validates_presence_of :user_id
end
```

user.rb

```
has_one :fee, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :fee
has_one :user_class, dependent: :destroy
```

view code

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: {action: 'update_profile'}, html: {class: 'm-form m-form--fit m-form--label-align-right'}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :fee, @user.fee do |u| %>
    <%= u.number_field :fee_hour, class: 'form-control m-input', placeholder: t('.fee_for_hour') %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.fields_for :user_class, @user.user_class do |k| %>
      <%= f.fields_for :class_detail, @user_class.class_detail do |c| %>
      <%= c.text_field :class_name, class: 'form-control m-input' %>
   <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Can anyone help me updating user independent table! Thank you in advance

Comment: 2 errors: 1) `@user_class` is nil, so you can't call any useful methods on it. 2) even if it weren't nil, method `class_detail` is not defined anywhere anyway.

Comment: Your associations look odd. What does a `UserClass` represent?

Answer (score 0):

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, fee_attributes: %i[id fee_hour fee_month], user_class_attributes: %i[id class_detail [id class_name class_category]])
```

That means you want to update class_detail from user_class, but you need to define [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

```
class UserClass < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :class_details
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :class_details, update_only: true

  validates_presence_of :user_id
end
```

Also, the form must look like this:

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: {action: 'update_profile'}, html: {class: 'm-form m-form--fit m-form--label-align-right'}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :fee, @user.fee do |u| %>
    <%= u.number_field :fee_hour, class: 'form-control m-input', placeholder: t('.fee_for_hour') %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.fields_for :user_class, @user.user_class do |k| %>
    <%= k.fields_for :class_detail, @user.user_class.class_detail do |c| %>
      <%= c.text_field :class_name, class: 'form-control m-input' %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And in your controller:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, fee_attributes: %i[id fee_hour fee_month], user_class_attributes: [:id, { class_detail: %i[class_name class_category] }])
end
```

---

**Edited:**

That all means class_details and user_class are associated to the user already. Build references model - child-child-model - child-parent-model from the single call not possible. You can build this references in the edit action. For example:

```
def edit
  @user.create_user_class!(class_detail: ClassDetail.find(n)) unless @user.user_class
end
```

Comment: Your code will end up with exactly the same error as the original poster.  Look carefully...  :)

Comment: UserClass belong to ClassDetail, not ClassDetail to UserClass. So @user_class was not set before, class_details must exist for user_class. Child update parent in the original poster.

Comment: @Leo i am still getting the same error. this isn't working

Comment: Ok, provide your log that relevant to the error. Also, add your edit actions, because that is not update action's error. But still, all that you need that is debug your state before edit view rendered.